# Abstraction level in provider , service and factory in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, abstraction

Recently I was asked this question in interview that out of `$provider`, `$service` and `$factory` which provides lowest level of abstraction? I have used all of three but I know only syntactic differences and having no idea about abstraction level.

Please answer with description. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the [**Angular JS** documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> The most verbose, but also the most comprehensive one is a Provider recipe. The remaining four recipe types — Value, Factory, Service and Constant — are just syntactic sugar on top of a provider recipe.